# how to easilly find desired jquery function in a js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor

examples:

```
$('.title').on('click', function(){
    do_something();
}

$('.title').on('contextmenu', function(){
    do_something();
}
```

I have a lot of such functions in a `.js` file.

Each time I need to edit the function (`Notepad++`) I need to press `Ctrl F` and search for `title` then press `Enter` several times while it is not found.

Because `title` and `click` and `contextmenu` are used a lot inside other functions.

Supprised but there are no names of jquery functions in the function list. There is only a word - `function` - totally useless.

I tried `Atom` and `Sublime` - the same situation. Pure js functions are there, but jquery functions are missing.

So what is your practice? How do you find desired `jq` function inside a large 
 `js` file?

Is there an editor, for Windows, having the names of `jq` functions on the sidebar?

If not - a potential solution could be a simple plugin for `npp` which should find the above function directly if `title click` or `title context` is typed into the search box.

Is it possible to create that plugin in javascript? If yes - please some help - where to start.

The third solution is a browser-based code editor, but that's probably too complicated fur such a minor task - have a function in a function list.

Any help?

Comment: Control-F for `$('.title').on('click'`? Also, rather than selecting `.title` each time, you might select it just *once*: `$title = $('.title');` then use and search with `$title.on('click'...`

Comment: `$('.title').on('click'` or `$('.title').on('contextmenu'` is a lot of typing (brackets, quotes...). Can't understand the second part of your comment, pls

Comment: You just have to store the selection in a variable. More efficient, less time spent typing, less time spent searching, better all around.

Comment: @CertainPerformance so, for example - `$var = $('.title').on('click')`. That's written somewhere in the body of `.js` file. Now - `Ctrl-F` and type `$var` - what is find is `$var` and not `$('.title').on('click')`. If I'm wrong, pls write a complete example.

Comment: No, see first comment - `$title = $('.title');` then use and search with `$title.on('click'..`. Assign the *collection* to a variable so you can re-use it, assigning the *handler* to a variable doesn't help

Comment: If you do `$('.title').on('click', stuff = function () { do_something(); });`, most IDEs should recognize `stuff` as a function within the structure of your script (PHPStorm does, at least). Beware that if you do it this way, `stuff` becomes a global variable though (gotta define it with `let` beforehand if you don't want it to be).

Comment: I'm affraid creating a variable for each desired function I will create another problem (messing and confusion with variables) while trying to solve the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Type comments above your functions and then search for those comments it will help you allot.

Comment: Fine. And would be better with a comment list. Doesn't exists in npp. Unbelievable.